# Point areas in an image using CSS and show some text on hover?

Tags: css

How do I point some places in an image using CSS (like google map address pin), and show some text on hover(like tooltip) i need custom tooltip which can hold even a Image in it?

Could someone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use image map if it was an actual image. In your case you should look for some js plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map to define the areas on a transparent image over the div and set the title for each hotspot:

See jsBin demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ItETOSo/3/edit?html,css,output)

HTML:

```
  <div class="divWithImageAsBackground">
  <img class="invisibleImage" usemap="#test">
  <map name="test">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,30" href="#" title="This is the first hotspot">
  <area shape="rect" coords="100,0,200,30" href="#" title="This is the second hotspot">
  <area shape="rect" coords="200,0,300,30" href="#" title="This is the third hotspot">
</map>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.invisibleImage {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==);
  height:32px; 
  width:280px;
}

.divWithImageAsBackground {
  background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png); 
  height:32px; 
  width:280px;"
}
```

Comment: can we customize the title showing on hover using css?

Comment: I think the title tooltip cannot be styled by CSS, but you can simulate a title with JavaScript and show a div that you can style yourself. There are jQuery plugins to do this too.

Comment: thank you so much. as u told i got the solution using jQuery. here in this http://www.walterzorn.de/en/tooltip/tooltip_e.htm

Answer (score 0):

Say your background image is on a div:

```
#myImage( background-image: url(someimage.jpg) );
```

Add a style of 'position: relative' to that div.

Then, within the div add a number of  elements, positioned where you want them using 'position: absolute'. Each one should have a unique ID which you can then reference to provide the pop-up for each one.

HTML

```
<div id='myImage'>
    <a id='hotSpot1'></a>
    <a id='hotSpot2'></a>
    <a id='hotSpot3'></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myImage{ background-image: url(someimage.jpg); position: relative; }
#myImage a{ position: absolute; }
#hotSpot1{ top: 100px; left: 150px; }
... etc ...
```