# make hover effect on different parts of an image, not html but an img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically i have a "blueprint" for a building project,i need to make it so that when they hover on specific parts of the floor a short description pops out.
something like this:[image]

Comment: The term you looking for to google is "image maps".

Comment: share your code for better understanding

Comment: check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

Comment: see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489389/point-areas-in-an-image-using-css-and-show-some-text-on-hover

Comment: @Danmoreng i think that is in deed what i need but how do i map it? any ideas?

Comment: @YejielIMP opening that image up in any image editor will offer you x and y coordinates at the mouse position, use those coordinates to establish polygons which are your map coordinates.

Comment: @YejielIMP You can use an online Image Map Generator tool. I think is the easiest way. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an Area Map. The syntax is as follows:

```
<map name="myMap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,20" href="somelink.html">
  <area shape="circle" coords="10,30,50,100" href="anotherlink.html">
</map>
```

You use the coords to define each area. You then can assign an ID to each area and make the hover items. Try it and let us know.

You can use an Image Map Generator online, there are plenty. I use this one: http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/ It is much easier than doing it by your own.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done by assigning this image as background to a div of the same size. Then position anchor links at the exact positions where you want the hover effect. Add a hover tool-tip as [given here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip)   and that's it. Everything can be done with pure css.

Comment: you will also need to assign the width and height to each anchor link which shouldn't contain any text.

Comment: great approach thanks for sharing it with us

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```html
<img src="map.jpg" width="100%" height="300px" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="50,50,10,10"  alt="building" title="building">
  <area shape="rect" coords="150,150,10,10"  alt="building + rooms" title="building + rooms">
</map>
```

set your coordinates in image which will you generate popup message

Comment: image link is dead